# ARMA estimates changed after GARCH

Tags: r, time-series, estimation, arima, garch

I have selected the best ARIMA(p,d,q) model via maximisation of AIC and got the estimates of its AR & MA coefficients.

However, after having subsequently modelled the conditional volatility with a GARCH(1,1) via `rugarch` package in $R$ (and having previously specified to consider ARMA(5,5) for conditional mean) the estimates for conditional mean comes out to be different!

Questions:

- Is it normal? Why just adding  a model for conditional variance I'm affecting the conditional mean model?
- Should I force `rugarch` to use the the same estimates I got before by modelling just the residuals of the ARMA(5,5) model with GARCH? Would I get "better estimates" or not?

Comment: In addition to the answer linked above, here is an intuitive argument. GARCH implies the observations have different conditional variances at different time points. Answer to Q1: Efficient estimation of a conditional mean model requires weighting the observations inversely proportionally to the conditional standard deviation. Answer to Q2: You should not force stepwise estimation as it is inefficient and moreover can be inconsistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the thread ["ARMA/GARCH estimation in sequence"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87600/arma-garch-estimation-in-sequence), joint estimation of the conditional mean and variance models is the preferred choice due to its greater efficiency and possibly some consistency issues in stepwise estimation.

**Answer to Q1:**
GARCH implies the observations have different conditional variances at different time points. Efficient estimation of a conditional mean model requires weighting the observations inversely proportionally to the conditional standard deviation.

**Answer to Q2:**
You should not force stepwise estimation as it is inefficient and may be inconsistent. The estimates from stepwise estimation would thus be inferior to those from joint estimation.