# Do we re-estimate all the ARIMA model when we add GARCH effect?

Tags: r, time-series, estimation, arima, garch

I wonder because the `rugarch` library on R allows to generate an ARMA-GARCH, but the coefficients of the ARMA are totally different from those generated by `Arima` from the `forecast` package.

I thought that the addition of the GARCH was only done by adding the GARCH, and not by re-estimating the model, am I right or am I wrong?

Comment: By coefficients, do you mean lag orders such as $p$, $q$ in ARIMA($p$, $d$, $q$) or "slope" coefficients such as $\varphi_1$ in $x_t=c+\varphi_1 x_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t$?

Comment: I mean "slope" coefficients, they're very different, and I keep the same lag orders.

Comment: This issue has been discussed multiple times before. See ["ARMA/GARCH estimation in sequence"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87600) and the linked questions in the panel on the right. You may also search for more such questions using relevant keywords.

Comment: Thank you, I'm sorry.

Comment: No problem at all.